# Elementary question about uniformly distributed random variable on specific set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose that we have a set $\Omega\times [0,1]$ where $\Omega$ is finite and stands for the state space, and $X$ is a random variable that is indepedent of $\Omega$ and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and denote as $x$ a realization of $X$.

What does it meand that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$? If for example $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\}$ would this mean that each state of $\Omega$ is equaly likely to occur?

Comment: $X$ only take values on $[0,1],$ and uniform distribution there means that any interval has probability proportional to its length. So $X$ cannot take any value in $\Omega.$

Comment: @WilliamM. thank you....I think my problem is solved